# Excel data validation: restrict to 10, 20 etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, data-validation

I am trying to use Data Validation in Excel 2010. How can I restrict entry into a cell to numbers divisible by 10?

Comment: It probably doesn't make any real difference for the answer, but please **[edit]** to clarify whether you want 10 or 12. Title says 10, question body says 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom - forumla in data validation -

```
=MOD(A1,12)=0
```

[image]

Replace 12 with 10 or any number. You can apply it to a range, just use the first cell of the range.